# Assertion `argc >= 2' failed. Abandon (core dumped)

Tags: c, matrix, opencl

I'm traying to calculat the multiplication of tow matrix using OPENCL with C:
`

```
#include <CL/cl.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <assert.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>

char* lire_fichier_source ( const char *nom_fichier )
{
 // On determine la taille du fichier .
 struct stat st ;
 stat ( nom_fichier , &st );
 // On ouvre et on lit le contenu du fichier .
 FILE* fich = fopen ( nom_fichier , " r " );
  assert ( fich != NULL );
 char* programme = (char*) malloc(st.st_size +1);
 fread ( programme, sizeof(char),st.st_size ,fich );
 fclose ( fich );
 
 // La chaine doit se terminer par ASCII 0.
 programme [ st.st_size ]='\0';
 return programme ;
}
 # define PRECISION 0.01
void initialiser ( float *a , size_t N )
{
 int k = 0;
 for ( int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
   for ( int j = 0; j < N ; j++) {
     a[ i*N + j ] = 1;
   }
 }
}
void imprimer ( const char *nom , float *a , size_t N )
{
 printf("%s::\n", nom );
  for ( int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < N ; j++) {
      printf ( " %f ", a [ i*N + j ] );
    }
  printf ("\n ");
  }
}
int main (int argc, char** argv )
{
 printf("j'ai entrée");
 // On lit l’argument du programme , qui indique la taille
 // des matrices a generer et multiplier .
 assert( argc >= 2 );
 size_t N = atoi(argv[1]);
 //size_t N=4;
 
 // On obtient un * device * de type GPU .
 cl_platform_id plateforme ;
 clGetPlatformIDs (1, &plateforme,NULL );
 cl_device_id device ;
 clGetDeviceIDs ( plateforme , CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU , 1 , &device , NULL );
 printf("je suis dans 1");
 
 // On cree un contexte et une queue d’execution .
 cl_context contexte = clCreateContext ( NULL , 1 , &device , NULL , NULL , NULL );
 printf("je suis dans 2");
 cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties( contexte , device , 0 , NULL );
 printf("je suis dans 3");
 char *source = lire_fichier_source ( "produit_matrices.cl" );
 printf("je suis dans4");
 cl_program programme = clCreateProgramWithSource ( contexte , 1 ,( const char**)&source,NULL , NULL );
 free ( source );
 // REMARQUE : Si le code du kernel contient une erreur
 // de compilation , c ’ est clBuildProgram qui retourne
 // un resultat indiquant une erreur . Donc , en general ,
 // il est crucial de verifier le code retourne .
 clBuildProgram ( programme , 0 , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL );
 cl_kernel kernel=clCreateKernel ( programme , " produit_matrices " , NULL );
 float a[ N*N ],b[ N*N ];
 initialiser ( a , N );
 initialiser ( b , N );
 cl_mem buffer_a=clCreateBuffer(contexte,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR ,sizeof( float )*N*N , a , NULL );
 cl_mem buffer_b =clCreateBuffer( contexte ,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR ,sizeof( float )*N*N , b , NULL );
 cl_mem buffer_c = clCreateBuffer( contexte , CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY ,sizeof( float )*N*N , NULL , NULL );
 // On specifie les arguments du kernel et on lance son execution .
 clSetKernelArg( kernel , 0 , sizeof( cl_mem ) , &buffer_a );
 clSetKernelArg( kernel , 1 , sizeof( cl_mem ) , &buffer_b );
 clSetKernelArg( kernel , 2 , sizeof( cl_mem ) , &buffer_c );
 clSetKernelArg( kernel , 3 , sizeof( int ) , &N );
 size_t nb_taches[]={N,N};
 clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( queue , kernel , 2 , NULL , nb_taches ,NULL , 0 , NULL , NULL );
 // On va chercher le resultat : CL_TRUE = > bloquant !
 float c[N*N];
 clEnqueueReadBuffer( queue , buffer_c , CL_TRUE , 0 ,sizeof( float )*N*N , c , 0 , NULL , NULL );
 for ( int i = 0; i < N ; i ++ ) {
   for ( int j = 0; j < N ; j ++ ) {
     if ( fabsf( c [ i*N+j]-(1.0*N ))>PRECISION ) {
        printf("*** Erreur : resultat incorrect [%d , %d ]: %f\n" ,i , j , c[i*N+j]);
        exit( -1 );
     }
   }
  }
 clReleaseMemObject( buffer_a );
 clReleaseMemObject( buffer_b );
 clReleaseMemObject( buffer_c );
 clReleaseKernel(kernel );
 clReleaseProgram(programme );
 clReleaseCommandQueue(queue );
 clReleaseContext(contexte );
 return 0;
}
```

this is the kernel of the program:

```
__kernel void produit_matrices ( __global const float* a ,
__global const float* b ,
__global float* c ,
uint N )
{
int i = get_global_id (0);
int j = get_global_id (1);
float total = 0.0;
for ( int k = 0; k<N ; k++ ) {
total += a [i*N+k]*b[k*N+j];
}
c[i*N+j]=total ;
}
```

please if anyone have the OpenCL thanks to execute it because it give me always "0"

While running a C program, I'm getting the following error and I can't seem to figure out why.
I have tried all google solutions but doesn't work

opencl:produits_matrices.c:49: main: Assertion 'argc >= 2' failed.
Abandon (core dumped)

Comment: argc is the number of arguments including the program name, how do you execute this in your terminal ?
should look like `./a.out something`

Comment: the program converts the first argument to int with `atoi(argv[1])`, without passing an argument to it how can it work?

Comment: i execute it like this :  gcc opencl.c -lOpenCL -o opencl && ./opencl

Comment: i don't understand how can i pass an argument

Comment: obviously arguments to the program follows it: `./opencl 4` (or any number you want to pass). And always enable optimizations and warnings: `gcc opencl.c  -O3 -Wall -Wextra -lOpenCL -o opencl`

Comment: thank you for your answer it is very useful but i have other problems, the program is stuck in the for loop and it only gives the first value of the array and this value is always equal to 0.                                                                                                                                                also, the last lines after the last for loop doesn't execute.

Comment: If you have further problems, you should post another question.

Answer (score 2):

As SidoShiro92 has pointed out in his comment, your executable expects you to input an integer number as argument in the console, for example `./opencl 5`. Otherwise the `assert` will throw a runtime error.

Comment: yes i try it but even withe the argument it still give me : Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)